# How to pass JavaScript class object as an argument to a function?

Tags: jquery, class

I have defined a class named

```
var Twilio_js = { conn, func: () {} }
```

now inside func, I am creating an img tag inside a div dynamically as follows

```
func: () { var thisInstance = this;
    var innerContent = 
            '<img src="layouts/vlayout/skins/images/close.gif" onClick="javascript:Vtiger_Twilio_Js.closePopup('+thisInstance+');return false;"/>';
}
```

The image is rendered properly, but when I click image it gives me error invalid identifier. How can I pass class object as an argument to a function?

Answer (score 0):

Scope of "this" is not working. You can pass with object variable name;
Like this:

```
  'onClick="javascript:Vtiger_Twilio_Js.closePopup('+Twilio_js+');return false;"'
```

Comment: well, i am not that expert to tell you the exact reason but it works for me passing object var to a simple function without "javascript:" prefix. This prefix is important with href but not with onClick. Try without prefix.